# IX509Extension XCN encoding?

Tags: certificates

I understand from reading [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378077(v=vs.85).aspx) 
that the X509 v3 extensions must be handcrafted. This involves the CRL, AIA, name and policy constraints, policy mapping, private key usage period, and subject directory attributes.

I tried to make a CRL distribution point but the result is garbage:

```
    $crlExt = New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509Extension
        $crlOid = New-Object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CObjectId
    $crlOid.InitializeFromValue('2.5.29.31')
        $crlValue = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('http://www.test.com'))
    $crlExt.Initialize($crlOid, 0x1, $crlValue)
        $crlExt.Critical = $false
```

Is there any reference on how to encode the values for each of the following? I have searched all over but no luck.

- AuthorityInformationAccess
- CrlDistributionPoints
- FreshestCRL
- NameConstraints
- PolicyConstraints
- PolicyMappings
- PrivateKeyUsagePeriod
- SubjectDirectoryAttributes

Note that this is about the certenroll com interface in Windows. openssl is not applicable here.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/35864912/ix509extension-xcn-encoding

Comment: Clickable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864912/ix509extension-xcn-enco%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bding